# sinchRTC pod build of app is failing linker error

Tags: ios, objective-c, build, sinch

I cannot build my app when I include the pod sinchRTC.

I get a linker error. See image.

Any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: Why down vote, please provide an explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove support for i386, we don't support that architecture anymore.

Use an iPhone 5s simulator or later